# Need help inserting timestamps using OracleBulkCopy

Tags: vb.net, oracle, timestamp, format, bulkinsert

I have a datatable, dtXXX, with a string column that contains date-formatted data. When I attempt to insert the data using OracleBulkCopy I get one of two errors: "ORA-1830 date format picture ends before converting entire input string" or "ORA-1849: hour must be between 1 and 12".

I've tried formatting the column in dtXXX as System.DateTime ("05/04/2020 7:46:00 PM", gives me the "ORA-1843: not a valid month" error) and leaving the format undefined. 
I've used multiple formats for the date string in the datatable: "12-MAY-20 19:46:00", "12-MAY-20 19:46:00:000000", "12-MAY-20 19:46:00.000000" and attempted to wrap the date in single quotes. I've tried changing the column format in the Oracle table to DATE and TIMESTAMP. Nothing seems to work.

The only difference is that when the Oracle column is defined as DATE I get the "ORA-1830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string" error. When the Oracle column is defined as TIMESTAMP I get the "ORA-1849: hour must be between 1 and 12" error.

I've also successfully inserted a line of data from the datatable into the Oracle database using a single insert statement and inserted the datatable using the bulk function with all of the Oracle columns defined as VARCHAR2 (as expected).

I've checked multiple data sources online and can't find any concise responses or useful info for this particular issue. Any help is appreciated.

dtXXX data:

Col1   Col2   Date

XXX    XXX    04-MAY-20 19:46:00

Comment: if you use date or timestamp as the data types, you might want to look into [this](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212) and then use something like to_date(value,format_mask), if the column is of character type, use to_char

Answer (score 0):

Quote from your question:

> I've also successfully inserted a line of data from the datatable into
>   the Oracle database using a single insert statement and inserted the
>   datatable using the bulk function with all of the Oracle columns
>   defined as VARCHAR2 (as expected).

If that worked for you, maybe you can just add a column of type DATE to your table (in Oracle), and then do the string -> date conversion there (you can the drop the original VARCHAR2 column after that, if you want).

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch4datetime.htm): "For each DATE value, Oracle Database stores the following information: century, year, month, date, hour, minute, and second."

When working with DATE columns, think: the "date format" as such is NOT stored.  In order to get a date in a certain format, use TO_CHAR() and pick whatever format you require.

Example: suppose we have 2 tables (representing your data source and your "Oracle" table)

```
create table dtxxx (
  col1 varchar2( 3 )
, col2 varchar2( 3 )
, date_ varchar2( 18 )  -- <- date as varchar2, BAD!
) ;

create table myimport(
  col1 varchar2( 3 )
, col2 varchar2( 3 )
, datestring varchar2( 18 )  -- <- date as varchar2, BAD!
) ;

-- dtXXX data
begin
insert into dtxxx ( col1, col2, date_ ) 
  values ( 'XXX', 'XXX', '04-MAY-20 19:46:00' ) ;
insert into dtxxx ( col1, col2, date_ ) 
  values ( 'yyy', 'yyy', '05-MAY-20 20:47:01' ) ;
insert into dtxxx ( col1, col2, date_ ) 
  values ( 'zzz', 'zzz', '06-MAY-20 21:48:02' ) ;
end ;
/
```

IMPORT

```
insert into myimport ( col1, col2, datestring )
select
  col1
, col2
, date_
from dtxxx ;
-- 3 rows created.

-- add a DATE column to the MYIMPORT table
alter table myimport add dt date ;
-- Table altered.

-- myimport now contains a "date" as varchar2, 
-- and an empty DATE column
SQL> select * from myimport ;
COL1   COL2   DATESTRING           DT   
XXX    XXX    04-MAY-20 19:46:00        
yyy    yyy    05-MAY-20 20:47:01        
zzz    zzz    06-MAY-20 21:48:02
```

CONVERT the varchar2 (string) values to date

```
update myimport
set dt = to_date( datestring, 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS' )
;  
-- 3 rows updated.
```

QUERY - using different date formats

```
select 
  col1
, col2
, dt
, to_char( dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) fmt1
, to_char( dt, 'MM/DD/YY HH:MI:SS PM' )  fmt2
from myimport ;


COL1   COL2   DT          FMT1                  FMT2                   
XXX    XXX    04-MAY-20   2020-05-04 19:46:00   05/04/20 07:46:00 PM   
yyy    yyy    05-MAY-20   2020-05-05 20:47:01   05/05/20 08:47:01 PM   
zzz    zzz    06-MAY-20   2020-05-06 21:48:02   05/06/20 09:48:02 PM
```

Once you have converted the "date string" to DATE, you can format it when querying.  DBfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d8d0cfd9df75c52ee5b644158daf2c6f).

Comment: Thanks @stefan , this is an option but I was hoping to avoid data manipulation in Oracle after the fact. What I've ended up doing was a line by line insert and defining the date field as a date in the insert statement. It's not as timely as just bulk inserting but I guess the end user can't have it both ways. Thanks for the input though! Appreciated.